# Permutations - bug in Wolfram Alpha?

Tags: permutations, wolfram-alpha

I've got question whether Wolfram Alpha has bug in showing permutations. Check permutation rules, list, and two-line notation in [this permutation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=permutation%20%281%202%204%29%283%205%29%286%208%207%29).

I'd expect same result as was on [Wolfram Alpha blog](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2011/11/29/working-with-permutations-in-wolframalpha/) (first image).

Is it just some other convention or bug?

Comment: Looks right to me

Comment: Also, when in doubt, check with another program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two conventions, some read from right to left, some from left to right. Obviously they don't give the same result, so you need to be sure which you're working with.